# Unicode codepoint to Rust string

Tags: rust, unicode, utf-8

I'm just learning Rust, so I apologize if there is an easy way to do this that I've missed. I have a program that gets unicode codepoints as strings at runtime, and I'd like to convert those codepoints to Rust strings containing the characters they represent. Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to define `parse_unicode` for the below code.

```rust
fn parse_unicode(input: &str) -> String {
    input.to_string() // not working implementation
}

#[test]
fn test_parse_unicode() {
    let parsed_content = parse_unicode("1f44d");
    assert_eq!(parsed_content, String::from("\u{1f44d}"));
}
```

I see there's a [function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) to go from byte arrays to to strings, so if I wrote code myself to parse these codepoints out into byte arrays I could then convert them to strings, but I'm hoping there's a more idiomatic (or at least easier) approach.

Comment: how would you differentiate two codepoint ? Your question doesn't make must sense, work for return a char but not a string currently see https://lib.rs/crates/unicode_reader

Comment: with your requirement best you can do is https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=61efa16292a885d63b6a65693150e082

Comment: @Stargateur do you mean how would I delineate two codepoints in the same input? In the input they're split up by dashes, like "1f1e6-1f1eb". I figured if I could convert one codepoint it would be easy to split the string on "-" and work the rest out, but I should have explained that in the question. Sorry about that. It looks like the code you linked basically solves my problem though, if you want to post that as an answer.

Comment: feel free to self answer I have not much time so I need to speed up my procrastination.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stargateur has basically solved my problem with code linked in the comments, which looks like this:

```rust
use std::num::ParseIntError;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum Error {
    Int(ParseIntError),
    Unicode(u32),
}

fn parse_unicode(input: &str) -> Result<char, Error> {
    let unicode = u32::from_str_radix(input, 16).map_err(Error::Int)?;
    char::from_u32(unicode).ok_or_else(|| Error::Unicode(unicode))
}

#[test]
fn test_parse_unicode() {
    assert_eq!(parse_unicode("1f44d"), Ok(''));
}
```